Unstable PID control when input voltage changes suddenly
I am working on a bidirectional DC/DC converter project consisting of a cascaded connection of 2 topologies (DAB and buck-boost.) I am testing this circuit in boost mode with closed-loop control. Parameters of the converter are as follows:

High voltage side (output) : 800V DC
Medium voltage side: 600V DC
Low voltage s ide(input): 48V DC

Triple phase shift modulation is implemented in the DAB converter side. Also can be seen from the simulation figure that, for the buck-boost side, PI control is implemented to adjust the duty cycle of the external half bridge.
The mid-voltage side voltage is controlled by the external half bridge. When I suddenly change the input voltage, the PI control can provide good stability to the system, but I can't find a solution because the recovery time is too long for the output voltage of PID (which should normally be more stable than PI.) Any suggestions?
Here is the simulation model in MATLAB Simulink

PID control implementation is set to adjust the inter bridge phase shift ratio of the DAB converter, as can be seen here:

Input voltage change (+- %10) experiment is shown here:

High voltage side:

Medium voltage:


The DAB transfer function (TF) is rather friendly I would say in classical voltage-mode control. However, the buck-boost TF hosts a RHP zero which limits the crossover frequency: you usually can't cross over beyond 20% of the worst-case RHP zero position. Did you account for this fact in your design when stabilizing the loop for a bi-directional usage?

Hello @VerbalKint, thank you for your concern. Actually, since I was a bit lacking in control theory as a theoretical background, I was not taking into account the RHP zero term and its relationship with the crossover frequency. But I understood that I should also do PID control on the buck-boost part to adjust RHP zero posit. Also, I can look at the TF of the control loop using the PID tuner in this converter, otherwise, MATLAB does not allow me to do linear analysis in this simulation. Besides, I think you are good at control theory. Can you recommend me a resource on this subject?

The first thing you need to do, is obtain the control-to-output TF of your converter in both operating modes (DAB and buck-boost) in the worst case. With that plant TF, you can infer a control strategy for both modes with adequate margins and crossover frequencies. You can take a look at my last book which is a practical manual on the subject. It can be seen as a crash course on control theory for quickly stabilizing power converters. Cheers!
